# Beep Missing Intermittenly

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, timer, beep

I’m new to Python and thought I’d write a small Windows timer program using the Tkinter GUI.  The timer beeps at the beginning and at the end of five seconds.  The timer is activated by clicking on a Start Button, pressing the Enter key, or pressing the Spacebar key.  The timer needs to go into standby after it finishes and then start again on command.

The timer times, and is accurate (it needs to be accurate to less than 0.03 seconds).  However, sometimes (but not predictable) either the start beep does not sound or the end beep does not sound.  No RunTimeError is produced.  How can I make sure the beeps occurs every time?

```
from Tkinter import *
from time import time
from winsound import Beep

class Timer(Frame):  
    """ Implements a timer frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent = None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.timestr = StringVar()                

    def _update(self): 
        """ if 5 seconds is up, then beep, else loopback """
        self._elapsedtime = 5.0 - (time() - self._start)  
        if self._elapsedtime < 0.0:
            Beep(1500, 2000)
        else:
            self._timer = self.after(1, self._update)

    def StartKey(self, event):
        """ If Enter key or Spacekey is pressed """
        self.Start()

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the timer """
        self._start = time()
        Beep(4000, 200)
        self._update()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300+30+30')
t = Timer(root)
t.pack(side=TOP)

"""" Big Start Button """
b = Button(root, text='Start', fg = 'black', bg = 'green', \
           height=2, width=10, font=('Ubuntu Mono', '40', 'bold'), \
           command=t.Start).pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=30)

"""" Bind Enter key and Spacebar  to starting the timer """
t.bind("<Return>", t.StartKey)
t.bind("<space>", t.StartKey)
t.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe a second call immediately after an initial call is more reliable. Try replacing each call with two calls, e.g. `Beep(1500, 1); Beep(1500, 1999)`.

Comment: why are you using a value of `1` when calling `after`, and why do you call it in a loop? ? If you want to play the beep in 5 seconds, why not just use `after(5000, Beep, 1500, 2000)`?

Comment: Thanks @Bryan.  The reason for the loop is to execute some code I deleted for the purpose of this post.  I didn't want to inundate with code that is not germain to my issue.  The code left out uses `label` to display the countdown in integer seconds.  Eventually, the timer will be longer than 5 seconds.  the `after` serves as a callback to keep the integer countdown running inside the `else` (above the `after`).  I selected ` 1 ` in the` after ` just to keep the delay to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks, @eryksun!  Your suggestion to add a second `Beep` works, but with one additional issue.  Adding two `Beep` statements appears to add a slight (seems to be about 0.2 seconds) delay from the time I press the key to the time the initial beep is heard.  The purpose of this application is for one person to start the timer when an event is visually observed by judges.  With the .2 second (or whatever it is) delay of the beep, I'm concerned the judges will think the timer operator was slow to start the timer.  Thoughts?

Comment: Try creating some .wav files with the beeps that you need to play them instead with `PlaySound`. For example, `winsound.PlaySound(r'C:\Windows\Media\ding.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_ASYNC)`.

Comment: Thanks, again @eryksun!  Using `winsound.Playsound` to play a `.wav` file instead of using `Beep` seems to speed up the time to hear the sound.  However, the same problem of erratically not beeping when it should.  I added a delay of 1 ms with a `self.after(1)` command before both the start and the stop sounds seemed to fix my problem.  I can compensate for the invoked delay by making the trip to be less than 0.001 rather than 0.0.